# PHP and Smarty cant get IF to work

Tags: php, if-statement, smarty

I have this code that I cant get working.What have I missed? I want the to last divs to show on all pages except index.php

```
{if $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI eq "index.php"} 
<div id="banner_container">
    <div class="center">
 {else}
 <div id="banner_top_container">
 <div class="center clearfix">
 {/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

you might be needing the leading slash on the REQUEST_URI environmental...

```
{if $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI == '/index.php'}
```

*-or-*

```
{if $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|strstr:'index.php'}
```

*-or-*

```
{if $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|strpos:'/index.php' === 0}
```

A cleaner approach would be to assign "page" variable to the smarty instance

```
$smarty->assign('page','index');
```

in which you can then test

```
{if $page == 'index'}
```

As any additional query string parameters on your index page will cause your very explicit match to fail

Comment: But what if we have the url sometext.tld  instead of a page name what should I then have between the "" I tried with the full url and also nothing and just / and this doesnt work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, why don't you try echoing  $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI to understand its content, you may not even have a REQUEST_URI in some cases. What I suggest is within your PHP code you should call var_dump($_SERVER) to understand what environmentals are available to assist you.

Comment: I have now

    {if $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI == '/' || 'index.php'} 
 <div id="banner_container">
 <div class="center">
    {else}
     <div id="banner_top_container">
     <div class="center clearfix">
    {/if}

The first divs shows correct on / and index.php but it also show on all other pages and here i want to show 

     <div id="banner_top_container">
     <div class="center clearfix">

Please advice

Comment: because {if 'index.php'} is going to evaluate as true...  {if $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI == '/' || $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI == '/index.php'}